# Set board manager as ATmega16

Tags: arduino-ide

I tried to download the ATmega16 board in my Arduino. I have set below URL under File->Preference->Additional board manager URL

`https://mcudude.github.io/MightyCore/package_MCUdude_MightyCore_index.json`

I am getting below attach images. How can we resolve this error and install atmega16 board manager?

I am using Arduino version 1.6.9. I don't have any issue in opening MightyCare and Arudino URL from my chrome browser.

[image: Error_in_BoardManager]

Comment: Does the download error occur if you test it with a different JSON index from another project? That would tell you whether or not the problem was specific to this package.

Comment: I believe you will get the same error even if you did not have the MightyCore additional URL added to your preferences. This might be caused by network security settings preventing the Arduino IDE from downloading the file. Try whitelisting the Arduino IDE in your firewall software. You can configure proxy settings in the network tab of **File > Preferences** if necessary.

Comment: @ContinuousLoad - Yes. the download error occur irrespective of JSON index or URL.

Comment: @per1234 - It seems Arduino IDE is not looking for mightcore URL mentioned under Preference. It is my personal laptop. I am not sure where i have to check for the network security settings. Note- Earlier i have no issue with the old json URL. Issue raised only when I update the mightcore URL.

Comment: "Issue raised only when I update the mightcore URL" Have you verified this by removing the MightyCore additional Boards Manager URL from your preferences and opening Boards Manager? Boards Manager always attempts to download the official Arduino Boards package index file first followed by the additional URLs. It has the unfortunate behavior of giving up after the first URL that fails download. So if the Arduino URL fails then it won't even attempt your additional URLs.

Comment: @per1234 I have tried 3 different options. 1.Arduino default package URL alone 2. mightyCore URL alone 3. Both URL by seperated using comas. All three different options thrown same error saying Arudino default URL unable to download.

Comment: Great, so we now know the problem has nothing to do with MightyCore. Can you open the page https://downloads.arduino.cc/packages/package_index.json from the browser on your laptop?

Comment: @per1234 Apologies! For not giving enough info in my question. Yes I am able to open the json page(mightycare and arduino) from my browser without any issue.

Comment: Definitely look into whether the problem is caused by your network security settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyone help here.

I have resolved by few steps.

1) File -> preference -> Board manager URL as like below. Basically URL are seperated by commas.
`http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json,https://mcudude.github.io/MightyCore/package_MCUdude_MightyCore_index.json`

2) Deleted the tmp file (package_index.json.tmp) which is in the path `C:\Users\SIMBU\AppData\Local\Arduino15\`

This helped me to resolve the issue.